# The minimum number of times the while loop is executed is?

Tags: c, while-loop

what is the minimum number of times the while loop is executed?

Is it zero?

Not talking about **DO**

Comment: Have you tried to check by yourself?

Comment: `int i = 42; while(0) { printf("The answer is %d\n", i); }`

Answer (score 9):

Depends on how you write it.

If `while(){}`, then yes, the minimum number of times is 0.

If `do{}while()`;, then the minimum number of times is 1

If not talking about the **DO**, then it's 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (  condition ) {
    /* stuff */
 }
```

Unless condition is true stuff will not happen

Answer (score 1):

if it's

```
while(cond) {
    // code
}
```

then minimum count is 0

BUT if it's

```
do {
    // code
} while(cond)
```

then minimum count is 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the while's condition isn't satisfied at the first time, the loop is executed zero times.

Answer (score 0):

`While` (not `Do-While`) will execute zero times if the condition is not met.